# What's the ETA on Public Beta?

Tags: discussion, public-beta

Just curious, about when will be break out of our private beta cage and let the hordes in? Are there any special benchmarks we need to meet first? Special A51 stats?

Answer (score 2):

As you will see from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158144/154443) on Meta.SO:

> A site is generally in Private Beta for 7 days. However, some sites have remained in Private Beta for a little longer in order to allow the committers enough time to actually build up enough good content to move to Public Beta.

and Anna Lear's comment:

> We review each site on a case-by-case basis, and we haven't discussed Politics yet, so right now I don't know which way that one's going to go.

So, we should expect it to be at least a week, but probably not much more. The stats are looking pretty good in terms of numbers of questions asked and answered.

Comment: If I remember correctly Politics was in private beta for around 2 weeks or so because we had some scope problems, and we had to figure out how to keep it from becoming a discussion forum.